# How to fix errors when packaging Unity to an apk file

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I'm getting an error while packaging Unity to an apk file. It takes a long time but always fail.

These are the errors:
[image]
It is the command.

Tried different solutions found on the Internet, but they didn't work (things such as creating files in the folder *GrandleTemplates*, change many settings, etc).

Comment: i am new in stack overflow, so if i have some mistake,just point out.